# Argument of type 'MatTableDataSource<EmpElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collection<unknown>'.

Tags: angular, mat-table, ngx-pagination

I am facing this issue if i am adding ngx-paginator to mat table.
Please help me out.

```
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource| paginate: {itemsPerPage: size, currentPage: p, 
   totalItems: EMP_DATA.length}" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
        
    .
    .
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event;paginate(p)"


    [responsive]="true"
    ></pagination-controls>
```

IN ts file

```
         size = 10;
         pageIndex = 0;
         p=1;
         dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<EmpElement>(this.EMP_DATA);

          paginate(event: any) {
          this.pageIndex=event;
            }
```

Comment: What's the structure of `EmpElement`?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I am assuming that EmpElement is not an array

Change below line :

```
 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<EmpElement[]>(this.EMP_DATA);
```

Comment: Argument of type 'EmpElement[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EmpElement[][]'.
  Type 'EmpElement' is missing the following properties from type 'EmpElement[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: Structure of EmpElement -  EMP_DATA: EmpElement[] = [{..............}]

Comment: @shruti Jain , I have updated the answer, kindly check now

Comment: Hi, but again it shows me error.                                                                        
         EmpElement only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.